# active session limit configuration keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I installed version 18.0.0 of the keycloak for the active session limit option, when I put this option "required" my web application does not work I have an error "invalid username and password", and if I put the option to "disabled" the app works correctly.
Can you help me please?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration won't work, because there are 'REQUIRED' and 'ALTERNATIVE' executions in the same level. So, keycloak ignores all ALTERNATIVE s.
You should add one sub flow and add all executions and flows into it except **User Session Count Limiter**, then make this sub flow required. For more information refer [here - at the end of the page](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/server_admin/topics/authentication/flows.adoc)